# how to go to a particular part of the code to execute it in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using this snippet code below, how do I loop back to the line that says:

```
                 var boxTextWidth = 0;
```

and continue excuting from there, like a goto type of execution.
I don't want the $.post line and lines above it to execute

```
 $("#left,#a-z_left").change(function()
 {
                    var getData = $("#left").val() + "_" + $("#a-z_left").val();
                    $.post("v.php",{table : getData}, function(data)
                    {
                            $("#left_list_div ul").html(data).delay(5000);
                            var boxTextWidth = 0;
                            var boxWidth = $('#insertData1').innerWidth();



                   $("#insertData1").each(function()
                   {
                              // how to loop back to var boxTextWidth = 0 without executing the $.post line
                   });
                });
   });
```

Comment: Can't you just make it a separate function?

Comment: By the way ... let's pretend that `goto` doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks grc, are there any other solutions?

Comment: @jrummell Yeah, right: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=goto

Comment: GOTO has always been a very baaaaaaaaaaad practice: only the coder can (while writing it) understand it. Once the code goes to production, only g.o.d. can interpret it afterwards. Many times EVEN the original coder cannot understand it .... and starts all over again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to my knowledge. To achieve the effect, put the code block you want executed twice in a separate method (i.e. make it reusable) and call it as many times as you need. I don't entirely grok what you're trying to do, but I'm suggesting something like this:

```
function setBoxAttrs( width, id ) {
        boxTextWidth = width ;
        boxWidth = $( '#' + id ).innerWidth();
}

$("#left,#a-z_left").change(function () {
    var getData = $("#left").val() + "_" + $("#a-z_left").val();
    $.post("v.php", {
        table: getData
    }, function (data) {
        $("#left_list_div ul").html(data).delay(5000);
        setBoxAttrs( 0, 'insertData1' );
        $("#insertData1").each(function () {
            setBoxAttrs( 0, 'insertData1' );
        });
    });
});
```